# Get DateTime independent from CultureInfo.Calendar

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

this seems to be an easy one but I consider it tricky to provide an elegant solution.

There is the need of getting the UTC date time as string - but independent from the CultureInfo settings. In a way with good performance - as it needed several times per minute.

So if e.g. Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture is set to Thai, it shall print **2020**-10-08 and not **2565**-10-08.

As said, looking for an lightweight solution where I do not need to change Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture back and forth.

I tried to cover the problem in the unit test code below. Amongst others, this currently prints

> Arabic returns 1442-02-21T13:03:28.0393847Z

> Thai returns 2563-10-08T13:03:28.3558814Z

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        StringBuilder assertionErrors = new StringBuilder();

        // each culture info shall return e.g. 2020-10-08
        var expected = $"{ DateTime.Now.Year}-{ DateTime.Now.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') }-{ DateTime.Now.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}";

        foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
        {                
            // ARRANGE
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;

            // ACT
            string originalTime = GetEventTime();

            // ASSERT
            if (!originalTime.StartsWith(expected))
            {
                // Append error
                assertionErrors.AppendLine($"{ ci.EnglishName } returns {originalTime}");
            }
        }

        var result = assertionErrors.ToString();

        Assert.AreEqual(0, result.Length, result);
    }

    private string GetEventTime()
    {
        return DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` into the `ToString` call:

```cs
private string GetEventTime() =>
    DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In general, culture-specific formatting calls usually have overloads accepting an `IFormatProvider` - which `CultureInfo` implements.